# How to add an image to a facebook post share html

Tags: html, facebook

I wanted to make pictures on my site shareable on social media but when it came to facebook I used this

```
<a class="social-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.My-Website.com/pic/Pictures/Mustang.png">
  <img src="http://My-Website.com/pic/facebook.svg" class="social-share__content" alt="facebook">FaceBook
</a>
```

but that just sticks the link into the title and content of the post. Is there a way I can attach the photo to the post as well?

Comment: I doubt that is available for HTML(web-sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the answer myself. According to FaceBook:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images. Images can be up to 8MB in size.

By following those guidelines you can get images in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing is not really made for pictures only, you should always share a link that includes the picture in the `og:image` tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.My-Website.com/pic/Pictures/Mustang.png" />
```

More information: http://ogp.me/

Best practices for images: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: with over 50 pictures that would be a bit insane!

Comment: why? with a server language, you can just create one file (for example, one php file) that returns the correct og tags with some parameter. it does not matter how many pictures there are.

Comment: Really how do you do that? Could you direct me to some good tutorials as to what you are talking about? Also would it require a lot of code (my current html file has 51 pictures and is about 2500 lines)

Comment: it really depends on your project/website, but you should create a separate thread for this and include what you have tried so far. it´s basic php stuff: a small script that takes a parameter, adds the og tags and redirects with javascript.